# MPMoviePlayerController duration is not being updated

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController, and I can successfully play a (local) video with it.

The duration property is not being set to the runlength of the video - even after I receive a MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification event, the value remains set to 0.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I can get a duration value for the main thread but not when I try to load it in the background thread.  I asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397896/asynchronous-mpmovieplayercontroller-load-has-no-duration-value

Comment: I didn't - I think in the end, I made another change to the code, and I started getting the correct numbers back. I have no Idea as to what caused the problem though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I eventually worked out that I wasn't properly casting the value for output.  Instead of:

self.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"Duration: %d",self.player.duration]

I needed something more like:

self.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"Duration: %f",(float) self.player.duration]

And ultimately output:

self.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Running Time: %d min",(int) ceil(self.player.duration/60)];