# Asynchronous MPMoviePlayerController load has no duration value

Tags: iphone, ios4, asynchronous, mpmovieplayercontroller

I assume that the `initWithContentURL:` method is not asynchronous.  I added the following methods to do the load in the background and then assign the temporary player to my variable.

```
-(void)createPlayer {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

MPMoviePlayerController *temp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URLString"]];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(passPlayer:) withObject:temp waitUntilDone:YES];

[temp release];
[pool release];
}

-(void)passPlayer:(MPMoviePlayerController*)temp {    
player = [temp retain];
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
//player.view.hidden = YES;
//[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player prepareToPlay];
}
```

The problem is when I print out the duration of the player I get this:

```
double duration = player.duration;
NSLog(@"duration: %f, duration);

console output:  duration: nan
```

I have added the `MPMoviePlayerControllerNotifications` to be notified when there is a duration value available, but even then the value is still 'nan'.  If I do the load on the main thread the duration has a value, but I don't want to use the main thread so my UI doesn't lock up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your initial assumption is wrong - initWithContentURL is async.

Comment: @Till Any documentation to point me to?

Comment: No, unfortunately all I got is plenty of experience using it. It never introduced recognizeable delays, even if the remote server was not/hardly reachable.

Comment: @Till Looks like you're right.  The line that was causing the push delay was `prepareToPlay`.  But, if I remove that line, the player won't play at all.  I tried setting a timer to call it a second after the view loads, but it won't play at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, to spell it clearly, none of the MPMoviePlayerController methods are using synchronous network access. They all return immediately when used properly. I would suggest you to remove all of that manual threading and check again. prepareToPlay also returns immediately in player implementations that I have done.

Comment: @Till I don't have any threading anymore.  I'm calling `prepareToPlay` in `viewDidLoad` the player won't play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official doc :

> Discussion
>   If the duration of the movie is not known, the value in this property is 0.0. If the duration is subsequently determined, this property is updated and a MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification notification is posted.

So use NSNotificationCenter to register the MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification notification.

Comment: I added the notifications and occasionally (and randomly) I'll still get a 'nan' value. Any idea?

Comment: but you check the duration in your method called by notification, right ?

Comment: Right I NSLog'd it in the selector method that the notification calls.

Comment: Maybe it's because you create the MPMoviePlayerController in a thread, are you sure that initWithContentURL is synchronous ?

Because there is a MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification notification to know when movie is available for playing.

Comment: No I'm not positive it is but I guessed it was since the NSData -initWithContentsOfURL is.  The reason I threaded it was because there was a delay pushing on the new view controller that contains the player, which I thought was that init method firing in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't create UI objects on a non-main thread. All UI operations must be done on the main thread, or odd things will occur. Such as, perhaps, the movie never loading and NAN being returned for the duration.

Second, `initWithContentURL:` probably *is* asynchronous or there wouldn't be notifications to let you know when the movie was actually loaded. Just create the controller as you would normally, subscribe to the appropriate notifications to know when the status is updated, and then check the status immediately just in case the movie happened to be a local file or already cached so the load was able to happen synchronously.

Comment: It seems as though the `init` method is synchronous.  It ties up the UI and lags the new view push--which is what I'm trying to avoid here.

Whenever I create the player with the `initWithContentURL:` method, or the general `alloc` and `init` and do `setContentURL:` it ties up the UI.  I could create the player later (like when they push the play button), but I was hoping to have it start loading sooner.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the movie player has not been able to calculate the duration. If you subscribe to the `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification` notification, you'll be notified if and when a value has been determined.

**MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification**

> This notification is posted when the
>   duration of a movie object is
>   determined. The object of the
>   notification is the
>   MPMoviePlayerController object itself.
>   There is no userInfo dictionary. The
>   duration value is reflected in the
>   duration property of the movie player
>   controller.

Source: [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW63)

Comment: I added the notifications and occasionally (and randomly) I'll still get a 'nan' value.  Any idea?